# Need zero value to show in query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My query has many left joins so I apologise for not entering properly to begin with. 
I do have a time frame that I use but I felt it was not needed originally. 
I just added it in.

My select statement has about 10-15 columns in my original query. 
-I did not include them because they are unimportant (just extra data needed).

My `FROM` statement starts with a table called Cases c.

From there I have many left joins that eventually connects to the inv_items table. This example I only included the left join showing the Cases table and Inv_items table

```
Declare @start datetime, @end datetime

Select @start = '8-21-2017', @end = '8-21-2018'


select  
  mcl.procedure_name [Procedure],
  ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME [Item name], 
  count(ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME) [Count]
from 
   Cases C   
   left join Procedure_done MCL on
     on mcl.case_no = c.case_no
     and mcl.Station_ID = c.Station_ID 
   left join Inv_Items II
     on II.Part_Number = mcl.INV_Part_Number
where 
  and ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME not like 'null'
group by  
  ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME
order by
  ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME asc
```

My database contains over 10,000+ active inventory items. I need a count for each item even if it has not been used. They are trying to eliminate products not being used.

I apologize if hard to understand. I self taught myself SQL only from using my database I work with. Other than that, it is foreign to me except for when I need something special like showing 0 values. I am thinking my constraints are limited but not sure.

Comment: Hey... you can't have the same alias `II` for two separate table expressions.

Comment: And what do `c.`, `mcl.`, and `sr.` refer to?

Comment: any of those can be taken out.

Comment: Sample data and expected result would clear up this ambiguity. What defines a used and not used item? Also, this clause is confusing: "from 
    Inv_Items II
left join 
    Inv_Items II on" is this the actual SQL you are running, because that's not allowed syntactically?

Comment: I actually don't really understand the question. Can you show more output?

Comment: I modified it hoping to clarify some questions.

Comment: The only way that could happen is if the `ii.invitm_item_Name` of 'Bronze' doesn't exist.  So is 'Bronze' in `Inv_items`?  Do you have a table that lists Bronze, Silver and gold as values that we can join to ensuring we always get the names?

Comment: If there are no records containing Bronze then Bronze won't be shown because there's nothing there to group. The server doesn't know there's a _potential_ for a record to contain Bronze. It can only see what's in the table right now. If you had a lookup table which contained those values always, and then this table here just contained a foreign key to that table, you could do it by making a join to the lookup table and grouping by the name there.

Comment: xQbert - Bronze is in the Inv_Items, but hasn't been used. That would need to show as a 0

Comment: what do you mean "hasn't been used"? Please clarify. It would really help if you could show us the source data where the query is returning the results from. And what the heck is `NOT LIKE 'null'`? Please tell me you aren't storing the string `'null'` instead of making your field _actually_ `NULL`

Comment: Then the above isn't your entire query.  You're eliminating the bronze records somehow but not showing it. Bronze is <> 'null' so that where clause isn't doing it.  Perhaps you need to use conditional aggregation instead of just counting and move those limits to the conditions `select  ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME [Item name]
     ,  SUM(CASE WHEN SOMECONDITION THEN 1 else 0 end) [Count]
FROM inv_items II
WHERE ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME not like 'null'
GROUP BY ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME
ORDER BY ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME asc`

Comment: Bronze, Silver, Gold are all INVITM_ITEM_NAME. I am looking for the count used in a particular timeframe. I happen to know Bronze wasn't used so when I execute my results, it is missing. I still need it to show. Here is an example                                                                              Item name                             Count
Anesthesia Circuit, Universal Flex2 187
Antibacterial Envelope, TYRX Absorbable - Large 4
Antibacterial Envelope, TYRX Absorbable - Medium 1
Bronze should show as 0 but it does not show at all.

Comment: Please add additional data to the question not the comments. Then it can be formatted for readability, thanks.

Comment: Looks like poor normalization has bitten you. You need a table of medal colors.

Comment: "Bronze wasn't used"...I asked you to clarify "wasn't used" already, but you just used the same ambiguous terminology again. Do you mean that _"there are no records in the table where the INVITM_ITEM_NAME column contains "Bronze"_? If so, then please refer to my earlier comment (starting "If there are no records containing Bronze...") for an explanation of why the results will not show "Bronze". It cannot show something which doesn't exist. You might as well expect it to show "Badgers: 0" as well. If that's not what you mean by that phrase, you'll have to explain yourself better. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. If you're looking for records "within a timeframe" then why doesn't your query contain a WHERE clause to restrict it by time? Have you over-simplified your example, as others have suggested?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I formatted the query to make it clearer and also removed a duplicated portion. However, there is a syntax error - `where and...`. Please double-check your query. Is it a typo or did you miss something out from the where clause?

Comment: Also please provide a small sample of your data in each table and the count results you would want to get from that small sample. This question is really all to with what is and isn't present in your data. I will say, one more time, that if none of the records in the table which are also matched by your where criteria contain the value "Bronze", then no count will be shown for Bronze, because, as far as the query is concerned, it doesn't exist, so it can't group it. That's just how SQL's COUNT function works. It can't provide a count for what is effectively an arbitrary non-existent value.

Comment: I already suggested a solution to this in my very first comment, above. If you didn't understand what I wrote, please say so and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: any items in the select that are not aggregated must be in the group by.  Since II is the right side of a left join it's possible that it's name may not be in the results.  So if you're after all possible "names" you need to select distinct names from that ii table ( a second instance) and and cross join it to your cases table so you get all possible  names as ADyson mentioned.  .  Regardless of how many joins there are or columns; post it all if you can; I'd much rather see what you're looking at as a whole and address all the needed aspects than try and piecemeal it.  We do want to help

Comment: We do really want to help; most of us are really passionate about it and you are to or you wouldn't ask for help and be self taught!  So don't get angry/frustrated w/us we're working to get to your level of understanding of the problem so we can help you!  Be patient with us and us w/ you and you'll see the benefits!

Answer (score 1):

Going back to the original post before the edits...  Somewhere along the way too much was removed that obfuscated the problem; and not enough included to really show us the problem.

The two fundamental issues I see are

1. Count needs to come from the right table (MCL) not the left (II)
2. The `and MCL.MCL_Status = '7'` in the where negates the left join so you need to move that to the join itself.

These other issues could be contributing in some way.

1. Where does table SR table alias come from on the last where clause limit?
2. Where does C alias come from
3. Where does MCL alias come from (table INV_ITEMS is represented twice?) come from
4. When using a left join any limiting value on the right side of the left join MUST be on the join itself or the left join becomes an inner join.
5. 'NULL' as string is different then NULL the absence of data.

So we need to clean up the `SR`, `C`, `MCL`, `II` table aliases and we need to move      `and MCL.MCL_Status = '7'` to the join instead of the where clause or the left join now behaves like an inner join (it is this line that I believe is eliminating the bronze record).  Now I'm not sure if you're using the word 'null' as a string to mean something; but usually this is bad form and we want to eliminate NULL (the absence of data) since dates can't contain null and I'm assuming c.Procedure_Date is a date; we need to change that to handle null appropriately by using the `is not null` syntax.

Then we need the count to come from MCL as we want the count from the right side table while the complete list of names comes from the left side table. So you only want to count "BRONZE" records that have a status of 7 of which there are 0 right?

THE BELOW IS STILL INCOMPLETE AND WILL NOT WORK UNTIL WE RESOLVE THE TABLE ALIASES..  However it is my hope that the identification of the above gives you sufficient information to resolve the problem.

```
SELECT ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME [Item name]
    , COUNT(MCL.INV_Part_number) [Count] 

FROM Inv_Items II
LEFT JOIN join Inv_Items MCL
  on II.Part_Number = MCL.INV_Part_Number 
 and II.InvItm_Active = '1' 
 and ii.PART_NUMBER_GUID=mcl.PART_NUMBER_GUID
 and MCL.MCL_Status = '7' 
WHERE (c.HIDDEN is null or c.HIDDEN <> 1) 
  and c.Procedure_Date between @start and @end 
  and c.Procedure_Date is not null 
  and ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME is not null
  and sr.REPOSITORY_ID = (@repository)

GROUP BY ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME
ORDER BY ii.INVITM_ITEM_NAME asc
```

The above illustrates why providing a MCVE (Minimally Complete and Verifiable Example) along with expected results is extremely useful.  We can't actually solve the problem because there's just too much wrong; all we can do is point to possibilities.